# In grails, using gsp how do I build a comma separated list of links from a collection of domain objects?

Tags: grails, join, gsp, taglib

Basically what I want is:

```
<g:fancyJoin in="${myList}" var="item" separator=", ">
    <g:link controller="foo" action="bar" id="${item.id}">${item.label}</g:link>
</g:fancyJoin>
```

and for

```
def mylist = [[id:1, label:"first"], [id:2, label:"second"]]
```

it should output:

```
<a href="foo/bar/1">first</a>, <a href="foo/bar/2">second</a>
```

The key difference between this and the existing join tag is that I need it to basically do a collect and apply tags over the initial list before performing the join operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a custom tag, something like:

```
def eachJoin = {attrs, body ->
    def values = attrs.remove('in')
    def var = attrs.remove('var')
    def status = attrs.remove('status')
    def delimiter = attrs.remove('delimiter')

    values.eachWithIndex {entry, i ->
        out << body([
                (var ?: 'it') : entry,
                (status ?: 'i') : i
        ])

        if(delimiter && (i < values.size() - 1)) {
            out << delimiter
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<g:eachJoin in="${myList}" var="item" delimiter=", ">
    <g:link controller="foo" action="bar" id="${item.id}">${item.label}</g:link>
</g:eachJoin>
```

Comment: I was hoping a tag existed in the standard library, but this is a reasonable way of solving it

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't do this in a GSP. Cluttering your view with loops and conditionals makes it hard to maintain the code and forces you to test with functional tests which are quite slow. If you do this in a taglib you clean up the view and testing is very easy.

Comment: there's no conditionals here, just a loop, the <g:each> tag is fairly acceptable, I don't see why a g:join tag which operates in almost exactly the same way shouldn't be

Comment: re-reading this a few years later, you're responding to a question about a taglib by saying I should use a taglib, not helpful, downvote